# What is the difference between "String[] s" and "String s[]"?

Tags: java, arrays

What is the difference, if any, between these two ways of creating an `array` in Java?

Method 1:

```
String[] s = new String[];
```

Method 2:

```
String s[];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: one just declares an variable, the other initializes it.

Comment: The first method won't compile either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to interpret your question,

```
// this was missing a size. So we need to add one.
int x = 10;
String []s = new String[x];
String s[] = new String[x]; // This is the same as the previous line.
```

The other form type of question is this,

```
//These are two null arrays.
String s[];
String []s;
```

So you can put the brackets before (or after) the array name in Java. That is a convenience the compiler offers, they're equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] s = new String[length];
```

This creates a new array of length `length` and initializes its values with nulls.

```
String s[];
```

This declared a new array variable, which has the value of `null`. It needs to be initialized before it can be used, and because it hasn't been initialized, it can't be said to have a length.

Comment: This isn't valid code, not without a size assigned to the created array. If such a size were given in method 1, then your answer there would be correct. Method 2 does *not* create a new array; it just creates a new variable of type `String[]`.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do; I've edited your answer further.